# Name is countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Let's say I'm writing a story and there's a character named Jim and he sees 10 identical people who have similarities with his friend Emily, in fact, they look exactly like Emily.

What would Jim possibly say?

> 1. You may not believe it, but I saw **ten Emilys** in the woods.
> 2. You may not believe it, but I saw **ten Emily** in the woods.

This is my best thought I could think of to illustrate the problem. So, is it countable or not?

Comment: When I first looked at this, "Emilys" looked wrong: normally, if there is a consonant before the y, the plural is formed by changing the -y to -ies. I looked this up, and apparently the y remains a y for proper nouns. https://grammarist.com/plurals/plurals-of-nouns-ending-in-y/

Comment: @JavaLatte I have edited my question. Thanks for the input.

Comment: You were right in the first place... Emily is a proper noun, so you don't change the y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The first is correct.**  In this case, you are not really counting the name but the person, Emily.  **You can definitely count people** (one person, two people, etc.) and thus you can say you "saw one Emily", "saw two Emilys", etc.

The second sentence doesn't make sense.  It implies, in a sense, that "Emily"  is both the singular and plural, like "fish".  "One fish", "two fish" (not fishes).  **"Emily", of course, is not the plural of "Emily"** and this sentence therefore does not work.